# What's the reason for my ASP.NET Cache never expiring, despite having a sliding expiration time set?

Tags: asp.net, caching

So, I've cached a value using the ASP.NET Cache object, with the following code:

```
Cache.Insert("TEST_VALUE", 150, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

As I understand it, this should mean that if nothing accesses that object for 120 seconds, it will expire and return null.

However, if after 10 minutes I run a page which writes out that value from the cache, it's still there. I know there's nothing else accessing it because this is all on a local server on my machine.

Am I just not getting how this should work, or have I missed something else?