# Cached item never expiring

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a class that contains the following property:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> CommentCounts {
    get {
        string cacheKey = "CommentCounts";
        HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;

        if (c.Cache[cacheKey] == null) {
            c.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, new Dictionary<string, int>(), null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
            c.Trace.Warn("New cached item: " + cacheKey); 
        }

        return (Dictionary<string, int>)c.Cache[cacheKey];
    }
    set {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["CommentCounts"] = value;
    }
}
```

It seems that the Trace statement only runs once, and not every 30 seconds after the Cache item has expired. The only way I can get it to refresh the Cached item is to make a code chance and rebuild the project, which is obviously less than ideal.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `set` part of the property is probably the cause - `Cache["key"] = value` is equivalent to calling `Cache.Insert` with `NoAbsoluteExpiration, NoSlidingExpiration` which means it never expires. The correct solution would look like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> CommentCounts {
    get {
        const string cacheKey = "CommentCounts";
        HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;

        if (c.Cache[cacheKey] == null) CommentCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        return (Dictionary<string, int>)c.Cache[cacheKey];
    }
    set {
        const string cacheKey = "CommentCounts";
        c.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
        c.Trace.Warn("New cached item: " + cacheKey); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. That said, what's the best way to update the cached item?

Comment: I added the modified code for the property that should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and [asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340237/what-are-some-possible-reasons-for-objects-stored-in-the-asp-net-cache-never-expi); it was never really answered, but there might be some helpful debugging tips in the answers.